# Does Google crawl embedded Feedburner feeds?

Tags: javascript, seo, feed, feedburner

Does Google crawl Feedburner feeds that are embedded in HTML pages using BuzzBoost javascript?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: what happens if you check the page source? if embedded Feedburner can be seen in html with JS disabled, then Google would index it for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Source just shows the JS link to document.writes for the content, so I'm led to believe that Google doesn't crawl it, because the content is displayed through JS.  I wasn't sure because Feedburner is owned by Google if there are any exceptions...but I'm learning towards believing that Google doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a spyder simulator to see what a crawler can actual get from your javascript. Generally specking spyder have some difficulties on crawling text embed in js but they are much more better that year before. Also if you republish a Feed that has been already taken by Feedburner on your website, probably you wont get a really boost on search engine for that content... Feedburner is a company of Google group.